# Have expectations increased beyond the reach of new users?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, elitism

I spend a lot of time reading through old SO Q&As in order to learn more about using Python.  It's a format I find more helpful than most of the official docs.

However, it seems that the standards for current posts must have evolved with a community who view content relative to their own experience.  It feels impenetrably exclusive.  The very posts and style I have always found most useful in my browsing seem to be considered unacceptable in light of current meta.

As an example: 
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value) from '12, with 21 upvotes and 5 favorites, vs. 
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027885/slice-list-of-floats-by-value-in-python) of mine from a few days ago, at "-2" as of this posting, despite a similar and slightly more informative question.

I have to add that the impression to a new-ish user just from seeing the meta discussions that post to the "hot" box is that SE is increasingly proudly draconian.  While it's certainly worthwhile to keep ever-vigilant against a descent towards Y! Answers, it's not worth paranoia.  It even seems like many users of moderate "scores" complain about this on meta only to be met by a very high-scoring user who retorts that things aren't nearly strict enough.  Is ivory tower seclusion the real goal, here?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late

Comment: This may be in a similar vein, but I've read that before, and I don't think it's quite the same.  Same disease, slightly different symptom.  This isn't a matter of "negativity," but elitism to the point of "holing up" in the tower and boarding the windows.

Comment: By new users, do you mean people that are new to the site or (also) new to computer science?

Comment: I meant new to the site, but new to computer science might be even more apt.  I certainly haven't yet gained enough courage to start answering others' questions.  I'd like to, but this very issue creates a timidity about not being expert enough.

Comment: By the way, this question is less ranty than other similar question, so I upvoted it. Thanks for posting a well-explained position (even if I think you are wrong) :)

Comment: I echo @BradleyDotNET's comment, all around.

Comment: I don't think being new to the site has much to do with it. I only joined in April, and have not felt any bias against new members. When I see old questions and answers, the rules have certainly gotten much more strict. But I think it's necessary. Once you gain more access to moderation privileges, and use them, you will see how much trash people attempt to post. Somewhat ironically, I think that people sometimes get the impression that there's really no need to be so strict exactly because a lot of bad content gets deleted, and they never see most of it.

Comment: @Xodarap777 Stackoverflow is rather kind to answers, but nobody likes questions as much nowdays, judging by the amount of upvotes given.

Comment: While I've had my account for 3 years, I only really started using it last year and I have not noticed any "unmeetable" expectations. Granted, I don't ask a lot of questions becase  so far more or less every problem I've had has had an existing QA on it, which I've been able to find with minimal effort via google. I consider asking a new question as an absolute last (usually desperate) option. Because of that most of my questions are (IMO) fairly well researched. I think maybe that's a bigger factor for how a question is received than how long you've been on the site.

Comment: If you review the result of a google query on "python find n smallest items in a list", would you still have asked this question?  If you say yes, does it still make sense to ask the question the way you did?  A lack of research is one of the basic 3 reasons to downvote a question.  And sure the expectations have changed, pretty small odds that the existing 360 *thousand* questions wouldn't cover this common need.

Comment: Back in the day, it was easier for people to dump their specs in a question and ask others to do their work for them.  It is less so today.  So when you say "I need to clamp an array to elements between two numbers, and make sure your solution is performant, chop chop" you can expect to get a much more negative reception now than, say, two or more years ago.  All that good will has been wrung from SO by the hordes of help vampires.  Don't be one among them.  Don't come here first, come here last. Try something. Ask when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sites standards have certainly changed over time; the post from 2012 would almost certainly not get 12 upvotes today! Its also not the "worst" old question out there. Yours wasn't great; or terrible. Sitting at -1 right now, your score reflects that.

That said, the past isn't an excuse anyways, so to the actual question of "Is the bar too high?"

I read a *lot* of questions, and a lot get downvotes. A lot also get upvotes. A simple explanation for the high occurrence of downvotes compared to previous years is simply that *there is a lot more crap*. People have more to look through, and less time to sit helping a single post along.

Is the bar too high? My personal bar is set at:

- Bothered to Google the question first
- Is on-topic/not a clear violation of site guidelines
- Uses complete sentences, and the occasional paragraph
- Actually has a problem statement/question
- Includes code if necessary (often is) and the code is at least in a code block

If it meets those conditions, I will almost never downvote. Honestly, I don't think that *the bar is high at all*, at least for me. I've even seen questions that don't meet that criteria upvoted by some users!

Even if you accept that, you could argue that it is too high for "new users". Beyond my belief that we shouldn't treat new users different than any other, that you should ignore the name/rep attached to a post when deciding its merits, I offer my own experience.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572233/using-large-values-in-dependency-properties-xaml) is my very first question. I had looked at SO posts before, and I'm considered a good writer by my peers, but I didn't read the help center (shame on me). It got several upvotes (not 12, but not negative).

Perhaps it wouldn't do well today, but I feel that it would. My point is, even as a new user, if you spend the effort to have a well-written and researched post, you will do just fine here on SO.

Certainly; "ivory-tower exclusion" is not the goal of SO. Keeping the site clean of:

> Plz provide the codez for < some assignment >, I tried everything but
>   it doesn't work.

Is the goal. An interesting discourse on a goal of SO: [How to Write Without Writing](http://blog.codinghorror.com/how-to-write-without-writing/)

Comment: The old 2012 question also accumulated those 12 votes over the last 2+ yrs...

Comment: I honestly believe that your linked question would receive one or two downvotes in the current climate, then maybe would get a couple balancing votes in the following few days.  Your post, for example, includes "thanks" at the bottom.  I certainly don't think this detracts from anything, but https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts meta disagrees.  Also, you didn't post your trial code.  Awhile back, you might get a couple correcting comments.  Today, it would be downvotes, I'm sure.

Comment: @Plutonix Sure, we don't know what the *initial* response is as opposed to how much it gained over time.

Comment: @Xodarap777 I noticed that when reading it again :) Like I said; didn't read the help center. I didn't want to edit to make myself look better either. If you know WPF, I'm pretty sure you could reproduce my problem (included the XAML, and a dependency property is something you know how to make). That said, you might be right, you might not, we'll never know. I see enough "Show the code" comments that I'm sure someone would tell me if they though the post needed it (if posted today)!

Comment: I think that your 2012 post with little exposition or previous research, which received a few upvotes and no correcting comments, only furthers exactly my point, providing another example.  I tried to pick one that almost exactly mirrored my post, which provided more context than it did.  The score difference is +21 to -2 (changed when I posted this).  I think that the discussion in one of the long answers to my -2 post is not only what I was looking for, but potentially very helpful to many future users, which is the point of SO.

Comment: @Xodarap777 I'm sure my post could be improved in a number of areas :) Rest assured that I *did* heavily research the problem before posting that question; saying "couldn't find anything" *can* be useful but isn't always. I'm not saying either post's score was correct, I only mentioned it because you did.

Comment: The post from 2012 is absolutely fine, and I just upvoted it and its accepted answer. It's not instantly obvious to somebody of moderate Python experience what the best solution is, it's a sufficiently generic and simple problem than many people will want a solution to it (as evidenced by its 12000 hits in 2 years) and is expressed with succinctness, with clarity, and with an easily Googlable title. While simple, it is a shining example of *how* simple questions ought to be asked, and entirely worthy of its upvotes.

Comment: @MarkAmery I bet it would get at least a *few* "What have you tried" comments, and possibly a few downvotes. I agree, its a decent old question. Not sure about a "shining example" but its not as bad as the OP says.

Answer (score 5):

The [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value) you linked to is so clearly written I can understand the entire question from its title:

> ### from list of integers, get number closest to a given value

What's more, it's presumably something that many people have *actually wanted to do*, given that as of today it's received almost 12000 views. The fact that it's clearly titled will have drawn clicks from Googlers seeking to solve the exact problem being asked, and they will have found answers. That is useful. It is Stack Overflow working as it should. It is why the question has so many upvotes.

Your question, on the other hand, lacks this clarity. Let's start with the title:

> ### Slice List of floats by value in Python

What does this mean? I can kinda guess that it's going to involve generating a list with elements from another list, and the decision about which elements to include in the smaller list is going to somehow depend upon their values. But it reaches nothing like the clarity of the first question's title.

You then go on to say

> I have a list of several thousand floats that I want to be able to slice by min and max values.

but this doesn't really clarify anything.

In fact, it's only from your example output that answerers have been able to carefully piece together that what you want is to filter a list to only the elements between a specified max and min value, and then sort by value. The sorting step isn't even mentioned anywhere in the question - it's only discernible from the example output!

This lack of clarity is why you have attracted downvotes.

If your title had been

> ### Filter list to elements between two numbers, and sort it

then the question would at least have had the virtues of straightforwardness and searchability.

Comment: Agree with the commentary on the posts; but this doesn't really address the thrust of the question.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET True, I guess - it merely addresses the specific posts that the OP has exhibited as evidence of the supposed shift in standards. Whether that shift is real, and whether it has caused an increased barrier to participation for new users, are questions I don't know the answer to.

Comment: I appreciate the perspective.  It is difficult to objectively assess one's own lack of clarity.  I'll use this as a starting point for questions I ask myself when submitting future questions.